# What is an undefinable ordinal? How large are the least undefinable ordinal and supremum of all undefinable ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, definition, cardinals, ordinals

What does it mean to say that a particular ordinal/cardinal number is "definable"? Where and how do we define this "definability"? If there are undefinable ordinals/cardinals, how large are the least undefinable ordinal/cardinal? How large is the limit of all definable ordinals/cardinals?

Comment: Some of those questions don't have answers.  In short, an object is definable if it has a definite description (in a suitable language).  An undefinable object does not have a definite description, so we surely cannot say what an undefinable object is, or how large the smallest one is.

Comment: There might be some set-theoretic terminology overlapping, but usually, definable means that there is some first-order formula (without parameters) which is satisfied only by the given object. Given that there are only countably many first-order formulas, the least undefinable ordinal is countable, so not particularly large. It seems, however, to be (much) larger than the Church-Kleene ordinal, so pretty large as far as countable ordinals go.

Comment: @tomasz: Not to mention that the definable ordinals are not an initial segment of the ordinals, since $\omega_1$ is always definable!

Comment: @AsafKaragila How large is the limit of all definable ordinals?

Comment: Probably very big. Since if $\alpha$ is a definable ordinal then the $\alpha$-th fixed point of any definable cardinal function (e.g. the $\aleph$ function) is definable.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/44129) by Joel Hamkins to a similar question on mathoverflow may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3):

Given a formal language with a well-ordering, the property of being undefinable (for elements of the well-ordering) is not definable in that language unless every element of the well-ordering is already definable.  However, by stepping outside of that language, we can talk about definability in a formal way.

On the one hand, every consistent extension $T$ of ZF has a model (called a *definable ordinal model* or *Paris model*) in which every ordinal is definable.  If $T$ has a well-founded model, then it also has a well-founded Paris model (and if such $T$ is complete, then every Paris model of $T$ is well-founded).

On the other hand, whenever we switch to a more expressive language and add reasonable axioms, we can typically prove that some ordinals are not definable in the base language. In ZFC, we can quantify over arbitrary languages as long as their domain is a set, and given a formal language L<sub>1</sub> (with at most countably many symbols), the least ordinal not definable in L<sub>1</sub> is countable.  However, it can be a very large countable ordinal, and it typically equals the supremum of ordinals $α$ such that a bijection $α→ω$ is parameter-free definable in L<sub>1</sub>, equivalently (for typical languages) the supremum of L<sub>1</sub>-definable ordinals that are countable in the analog of HOD for L<sub>1</sub>.

Also, assuming zero sharp exists, the least ordinal not definable in the constructible universe $(L,∈)$ is countable in $L$, and the least ordinal not definable in $L$ from a finite subset of $\{ω_1^V, ω_2^V, ω_3^V, ...\}$ is the least Silver indiscernible.

Regarding the set theoretical universe $V$, by extending it with a $(V,∈)$ satisfaction relation Tr and adding separation and replacement axioms for formulas involving Tr (alternatively, using a reasonable theory such as KM that proves existence of Tr), we can prove that the least ordinal not definable in $(V,∈)$ is countable.  The supremum of all $(V,∈)$ definable ordinals is the least $κ$ such that $(V_κ,∈)$ is an elementary substructure of $(V,∈)$.

Also, there are different philosophical views on whether "every ordinal is potentially definable by the human mind" is true, false, or meaningless.